# JSONPath format returned values

Tags: json, jsonpath, jsonpath-plus

I am doing some JSONPath plus queries and wondering if I can format the values returned?

For example, I have a path below which returns three values: day, month and year.

```
$..CONTRACT_AWARD_DATE.*
```

This is returned as 08 2011 05 for example

Is there any way I can get this to be returned as 08/05/2011?

Comment: No, there is nothing in jsonpath to allow string manipulation in the manner you require. You will have to retrieve the string and manipulate then.

Comment: @nimgwfc - If you are open to a [tag:jq] solution, please so indicate, e.g. by adding the `jq` tag.